# XML validation on XSD during XSLT transformation

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have this simple code to transform xml file with xslt

```
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
transform.Load("XSLTFile1.xslt", new XsltSettings(true, true), null);
XmlReader input = XmlReader.Create("XMLFile1.xml");
XmlWriter output = XmlWriter.Create("Result.xml", transform.OutputSettings);
transform.Transform(input, null, output);
```

How can I verify my output xml file on XSD **during** xslt transformation? for example: if xslt tries to make another definite tag (with the same name) and XSD don't allow it - xslt transformator will not do it (or generates exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0 is not schema-aware**. No compliant XSLT 1.0 processor has any facility for specifying the schema for the desired output and for validationg the output. Therefore, the XSLT programmer can perform the validation only as a second step, following the transformation.

**XSLT 2.0 specifies the features of a schema-aware (SA) XSLT 2.0 processor** that allows exactly this. SA can also validate the type of parameters, variables, intermediate (temporary) trees and documents obtained using the `document()` function.

Some well-known XSLT 2.0 SA processors are Saxon 9.x, XQSharp and AltovaXML. There are at least two other -- IBM's (part of WebSphere) and Intel's.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the XSLT transformation as required and then validated the output document using **[Validation Event Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162371.aspx#exampleToggle)**.

Answer (score 1):

[Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml) has a Schema Aware processor, but I think you have to pay for the license.

Alternatively you could just validate the output of the XSLT.

Comment: There are also two other XSLT 2.0 schema-aware processors, namely XQSharp http://www.xqsharp.com/ and AltovaXML http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html. Otherwise Paul is right, if you want to perform validation directly within XSLT you need to use a schema-aware XSLT 2.0 processor. Or you need to validate the output of an XSLT 1.0 processor, with .NET and XslCompiledTransform you have some options doing that, you can transform to a System.Xml.XmlDocument or a System.Xml.Linq.XDocument and then use their Validate method, or you write to a file as you currently do and validate with an XmlReader.

Comment: The benefit of integrating the output validation with the XSLT transformation is that you can get much better error messages: instead of merely knowing which line in the output document is wrong, a decent processor will tell you which line in the stylesheet caused it to be wrong, so the debug cycle is much faster. In fact, in some cases (particularly if you carefully document the inputs and outputs of your functions and templates with "as" attributes) the XSLT processor will be able to tell you at stylesheet compile time that your code will always generate invalid output.