# Automatically test many XML files after applying XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

We have a application which converts RDF file to desired XML file using XSLT transformation.
Using above application we generate more than 1000 files.
So I wanted to know whether is there any way in which we could automatically test all the new changes which we apply using XSLT?

Currently we are manually opening the XML files and checking if those changes are reflected on all the files.

So can anyone please suggest a optimal way to test the generated XML files automatically

Answer (score 0):

- You can validate your XML files against an XSD as a next step after
  the XSLT transformation.
- Some XSLT 2.0/3.0 processors are schema-aware, and support validation against an XSD as a part of XSLT transformation.

Useful link: [XML validation on XSD during XSLT transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318491/xml-validation-on-xsd-during-xslt-transformation)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you obviously need to define some rules that you are testing the generated files against. From your description it's not clear what these rules are, or where they might come from. So there are two parts to your task: defining the rules that the generated documents have to obey, and then actually running these rules against the output.

Depending on the nature of the rules, there are a number of technologies you could deploy: you could implement the rules in Schematron, in XSD (especially 1.1), in XSLT, or in XUnit. And then of course you'll need some kind of script to actually run the rules.